# Swift - display a sorted array with keys

Tags: swift, sorting

I am want to display the three highest grades along with the names

My code:

```
let gradesofStudent = [
    "Elias Brown": 80,
    "Baris Yan": 99,
    "Christian Najm": 70,
    "Sam  Chakra": 90,
    "Alain Elliot": 55,
    "Georges Obama": 77,
]
   var y = " "
   var name = " " 
func mainFunction(stDictionary: Dictionary<String, Int>) -> ArraySlice<String>{

        var emptyDic: [String: String] = [:]


   for (keys, value) in gradesofStudent {

    if value > 0 && value <= 59 {y = "F"} 
else if value >= 60 && value <= 69 {y = "D"}
else if value >= 70 && value <= 79 {y = "C"}
else if value >= 80 && value <= 89 {y = "B"}
else  {y = "A"}
emptyDic[keys] = y
    }

var arrayGrades = (Array(emptyDic).sorted{$0.1 < $1.1}).map{(k,v) in return(k:v)}
var firstThree = arrayGrades[0..<3]

return(k: firstThree)
}
let v = mainFunction(stDictionary:gradesofStudent)
print (v)
```

I am getting the following output:

["A", "A", "B"]

What I want to get is something like  [ "Baris Yan":"A", "Sam  Chakra":"A", "Elias Brown":"B"]

Since i can't seem to sort the dictionary directly, I can't figure how to display the names.

Comment: You can make your life so much easier if you would use a `struct Student` with `var name : String`,  `var grade : Int` members, computed property `var letterRepresentation : String { ...}`  and an **array** of instances. Btw: A dictionary is unordered by definition.

Comment: Swift 2 or 3 ? your code is giving error in Swift 3

Answer (score 1):

My two cents (according to the comment)

```
struct Student {
    let name : String
    let grade : Int

    var letterRepresentation : String {
        switch grade {
        case 0..<60 : return "F"
        case 60..<70 : return "D"
        case 70..<80 : return "C"
        case 80..<90 : return "B"
        default : return "A"
        }
    }
}

let gradesofStudent = [Student(name: "Elias Brown", grade: 80),
                       Student(name: "Baris Yan", grade: 99),
                       Student(name: "Christian Najm", grade: 70),
                       Student(name: "Sam  Chakra", grade: 90),
                       Student(name: "Alain Elliot", grade: 55),
                       Student(name: "Georges Obama", grade: 77)]

let threeHighestGrades = gradesofStudent.sorted(by: {$0.grade > $1.grade}).prefix(3)

print(threeHighestGrades.map({"\($0.name) - \($0.letterRepresentation)"}))
// ["Baris Yan - A", "Sam  Chakra - A", "Elias Brown - B"]
```

Is there no letter `E` ?

Comment: Silly typo: your `switch` will give `A` to grades `69` and `79`.

Comment: Oops. Thanks a lot @PauloMattos

Answer (score 0):

The below code snippet would give you the exact result you need:

let gradesofStudent = [
    "Elias Brown": 80,
    "Baris Yan": 99,
    "Christian Najm": 70,
    "Sam  Chakra": 90,
    "Alain Elliot": 55,
    "Georges Obama": 77,
]

var y = " "

var name = " "

func mainFunction(stDictionary: Dictionary)->ArraySlice<[String : String]> {

```
var emptyDic: [String: String] = [:]


for (keys, value) in gradesofStudent {

    if value > 0 && value <= 59 {y = "F"}
    else if value >= 60 && value <= 69 {y = "D"}
    else if value >= 70 && value <= 79 {y = "C"}
    else if value >= 80 && value <= 89 {y = "B"}
    else  {y = "A"}
    emptyDic[keys] = y
}

var arrayGrades = emptyDic.sorted{$0.1 < $1.1}.map{(k,v) in return[k:v]}
var firstThree = arrayGrades[0..<3]
return(firstThree)
```

}

let v = mainFunction(stDictionary:gradesofStudent)
print (v)